# Replacing anchor href value with regex

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to replace all the href values of the anchor elements in a web page by adding  url of my website before the href value.

Before you suggest XML/HTML parser, please know that I tried bunch of them, and they do great job, however all of them return HTML that is simply messed up for some of the websites that I'm trying to parse. That has to do probably with broken html that is written in the first place, but as I don't have control over that, regex is the only way here. So I came up with this code:

```
$response = '<h2><a href="http://www.google.com/test">Link</a></h2>';
$pattern = "/(<a .*?href=\"|')([^\"'#]+)(.*?<\/a>)/i";
$response = preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'html_href',  $response);
function html_href($matches) {
    return  $matches[1] . "http://example.com/" . $matches[2] .  $matches[3];
}
```

and it actually changes `$response` into:

```
<h2><a href="http://example.com/http://www.google.com/test">Link</a></h2>
```

Thats great. But later I found out that this regex somehow matches also this:

```
$response = "var href = $(this).attr('rel'); $(this).replaceWith('<a href=\"' + decodeURL(href) + '\"><span>' + anchor+ '</span></a>');";
$pattern = "/(<a .*?href=\"|')([^\"'#]+)(.*?<\/a>)/i";
$response = preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'html_href',  $response);
function html_href($matches) {
        return  $matches[1] . "http://example.com/" . $matches[2] .  $matches[3];
 }
```

and here $response becomes:

```
var href = $(this).attr('http://example.com/rel'); $(this).replaceWith('<a href="' + decodeURL(href) + '"><span>' + anchor+ '</span></a>');
```

I don't really get, how come this inside attr() method is matched and replaced? Isn't this regex pattern supposed to match only parts of a string that start with `<a` ? I would like to avoid matching things inside javascript...

Comment: What's the alternation pipe `|` doing in your regex? Use more negative character classes to constrain the matching context.

Comment: pipe was supposed to match double quote or single quote, but probably I got it wrong. Could you give an example what would you change?

Comment: `(<a .*?href=\"|')` means either `<a .*?href=\"` or `'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a few common approaches:

- Prefer `<a\s+` instead of `<a␣`
- Use `[^<>]*` thereafter instead of `.*?` for in-tag attribute skipping. (This is probably the main reason it supuriosly matched JavaScript elsewhere.)
- When you want to allow `"` or `'` use a character class `[\"\']` just like you did in the middle.
- Match the href= contents more strictly with `([^<\"\'>]+)` for example.
- Then ensure another `[\"\']` comes thereafter.
- And assert the end of the `<a` tag with `[^<>]*>` (that might be the other main culprit for not matching the desired tags/links).

Use `[^<>]+` again for the link text, if that coherently suits your input html. 
Protip: write such regex patterns in a lofty `/x` notation whenever you can.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

**PHP**

```
$re = "/(<a.*href=)[\"'](.*)[\"']/m";
$str = "<h2><a href=\"http://www.google.com/test\">Link</a></h2>2014-54-22 22:23";
$subst = "\1\"http://example.com/\2\"";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

[live demo](http://regex101.com/r/jC5wT9/3)

Comment: How to deal with specific url, how do I do that, means remove http:// from google.com after adding http://www.example.com